# How to make icons appear on tapping of screen as in gallery app

Tags: android, button, touch-event

When we run any gallery app we just open a photo. When tapping anywhere on screen , it generates a kind of snack bar in which there are many buttons like share,delete,edit,star,etc. When again tapping on screen all those items disappear simultaneously all together. Its a kind of snackbar at the top .
I want to know what's that effect called, and how it is used.
[image]

As in this image no icons are coming , but when i tap anywhere on screen some icons appear . ON top of screen name is there, and in button i am getting some options. I want all the options that are in bottom should be on top
[image]

Comment: I suggest that you take some screenshots, upload them somewhere, and link to them from your question, so you can explain better exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: I had explained it in better way, now please help

Comment: That looks like a `BottomSheetDialog` or something.

Comment: You can add this type of dialog either by using `BottomSheetDialog` or creating custom `Dialog`.

Comment: But I want the dialog to come from top, how to make it